# Automation studio send email and sending tracking to salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

is it possible to use automation studio to send an email and send tracking information back to salesforce? We can't see an option to send tracking data back to salescloud as we do in Journey builder.

Many thanks

Comment: Isn't it called "Salesforce Email Send" and not "Salesforce Send" in 2021? And it is an activity that shows up in Automation Studio while building out the automation: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWTPy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWTPy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, this is not possible. The current requirement for tracking to appear in Salesforce Core is the following:

- SubscriberKey / ContactKey must be PersonContactId, ContactId or LeadId
- The key must use the 18 character-length version of the Id
- Unless you use journey builder or Salesforce Initiated Emails, you must use a Sendable Data Extension which is located in the Salesforce Data Extension folder, as the audience.

It is the last part here, that the user-initiated emails fails to comply with at present.

**/* UPDATE */**

When you have your users integrated, you will see an activity in Automation Studio called "Salesforce Sends" - using this method will also send tracking back to Salesforce as IERs