# Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Salesforce Send Tracking (Non Journey Builder Sends)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio, marketing-cloud-connect

I researched this topic through Salesforce and was able to find only one thread as attached below
[Automation studio send email and sending tracking to salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181304/automation-studio-send-email-and-sending-tracking-to-salesforce)

The reply from Kenneth suggests that this works for Email/Automation Studio sends.

Question 1. Would this solution still work if there are sub-folders within the Salesforce Data Extensions folder?

Question 2. Also, can someone confirm that the tracking still flows through to Salesforce using IERs?

Comment: Just to add to this, I have been trying to test this feature through the Salesforce Data Extension folder but have not yet been able to see IERs coming through. Does the tracking still flow through IERs for this solution like Journey Builder tracking.

Comment: What is the ask? The question doesn’t clearly state it

Comment: Added comment below regarding to Automation Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test this myself, and it works for Salesforce Data Extension folder and sub-folders. The tracking is sent via IERs.

Comment: Awesome Ani! And yeah, it should work - edited my post from a while ago, given that there is an activity in Automation Studio called "Salesforce Sends" which only appear after the integration users has been integrated. I assume this is the one your are using? This should also work :)

Comment: aha! I did not know about Salesforce Email Send. I had never seen/noticed it before. I am assuming it was part of a more recent release. I will try to explore that in a future project. Thanks @Kenneth!

Comment: I Think It’s been there since May last year, but, yeah - it’s Not Well shown :) let me know If it works!